# How to create and use context to save users data after login in react

Tags: reactjs

i'm new to create and just getting to know about react context. I want user to login using API and if the server side autehnticate users successfully i want to save users information in the userContext so i can use it globally at will.

my problem is how do i pass the data to the context provider?, i read about this and the suggestion was that I should use useState and useEffect in provider to fetch data but that don't solve my problem because this data only come fromlogin component after user  login

Login.js

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import UserContext from "../context/UserContextProvider";

const Login = () => {
const { setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
 const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const submitHandler = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);
  let items = {username, password}
  let result = await fetch("/v1/users/login", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Accept":"application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(items)
  });

  response = await result.json();
  if(response.code === 1){
    //Note: I want to be able to add response to UserContext()
    setLoading(false);
    navigate(-1) ;
    
  }else{
    setErrMsg(result.message);
    setLoading(false);
  }
  
}

 return (
    <>

    {(
    
  <div className="LogHeight"> 
      
      <div className="row loginRow">
        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 logImg mobily">
          <img src={bannerImg} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 loginForm">
          
          <Form className="formLog" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <p ref={errRef} className={errMsg ? "errmsg" : "offscreen"} aria-live="assertive">{errMsg}</p> 
            <h4><b>Log In</b></h4>
            <br />
            <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="email">
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                value={username}
                placeholder="Enter Username/Email/Phone number"
                ref={userRef}
                required                
                onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}

              />

            </Form.Group>
            <br />
            <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="password">
              <Form.Control
                type="password"
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                value={password}
                placeholder="Password"
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <br />
            <Link to="/forget-password" className="forgotP">Forgot Password</Link>

           <div className="LogButton">
              <button style={{background:color,color:textColor}} className='btn mobileBtn' >Log In</button>
           </div>
           <div className="LogButton" >
              <Link to="/Signup" className='mobileBtn signup'>
                <button style={{backgroundColor:'#ffffff', textColor:'#000', border: '1px solid #cf0000'}} className='btn mobileBtn ' >Sign Up</button>
              </Link>
           </div>
           
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      )}
      </>
    

  );

}

export default Login
```

UserContextProvider.js

```
export const UserContext = createContext();
export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    //Note: how can i implement here to provide context.provoder with users value without making the APi call from within here
 
    return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user ,setUser}}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
    );
 };
```

After setting the users data into the userContext how can I also use this context to check if users is authenticated and if so to change `login` in NavBar to welcome `user.username`

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav";

const NavBar = () => (
  <>
    
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" className="navP">
     
      <Logo />
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">

        <Nav className="mr-auto">
          Note: change login to welcome user.Username
          <Nav.Link href="/Login">Log In</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
          <Nav.Link href="/Signup">Signup</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>

      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
    
  </>
);

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: Call your setUser function

Comment: You didn't provide your `setUser` function when using the provider; you only gave it `user` => `value={{ user }}`.

Comment: I don't have data to provide to setUser from within context provoder because i cannot call login component from within context provider and that's why i posted the question

Comment: I updated my question, I don't want to fetch data within provider, i want to fetch data from within login component and set the data to provider how can i do this?